# Passing event in RegisterStartUpScript not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have been battling an issue with javascript functions not being called when the call is generated using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript on a asp.net page.

After a long process of elimination I have found:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function jim(e)
{
alert('Jim');
}
</script>
```

Now, if I call that function by putting this on a .aspx page:

```
<span onclick="jim(event);">Show Jim</span>
```

when I run the page and click the span, in Firefox, the function is called and the alert shows.

If I try to call that function from code behind like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "M3", "jim();", true);
```

it works. The function is called and the alert shows.

If I try to call that function from code behind like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "M3", "jim(event);", true);
```

it DOES NOT work. Nothing happens.

So, if I include the word 'event' as a parameter, on a .aspx page - Firefox couldn't care less and it works.

If I call the same function from code behind with the 'event' word included as a parameter, it does not work.

If I remove the word 'event' as a parameter and call from code behind, it works. Any ideas? Driving me nuts. I need to pass 'event' to the function as IE needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to replicate your issue. Seems that when the script is registered in the .cs, the browser console window complains that 'event' is undefined. Maybe check for nulls before registering your script.

Comment: When you say 'check for nulls before registering your script' what should I check? I have been thinking about this and ... does this make sense? When I click a span tag (in my code example above) - an event is being raised - the span has been clicked. When I register a script, no event is actually taking place - it is simply that a bit of javascript is being written to a page. So, that is why there is no 'event' and 'event' is undefined. Not sure how to get over this - other than to find a way to omit code which wants to know about the event.

Comment: Okay I think I've got it. When I pass 'event' in the OnClick method, it is passed as a click event, rather than a property named 'event'. When the script is registered on the server side, it is not called as an OnClick event, therefore, 'event' does not exist as a property. Try declaring the property 'event' like: 'var event = "Hello World"' somewhere in the Script tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Firefox doesn't have event global variable defined and we need to explicitly pass events to functions which have event parameters.